# Sorting two lists ignoring any non-numeric values?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Relatively new to Mathematica, so this might be an easy question. With two lists I need to sort both by one of them, while ignoring any non-numeric values

Example:

```
x={a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
y={-2, Indeterminate, -3, -Infinity, -1, Apples, 5};
```

(Also have z=Partition[Riffle[x,y], 2] if that's a little bit better to work with)

Result looking for:

```
xn={g, e, a, c}
yn={5, -1, -2, -3}
```

(Or zn equivalent from using z)

Comment: Consider asking on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/, which is currently *the* place to ask any Mathematica-related questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
Transpose@Reverse@SortBy[Cases[Transpose[{y, x}], {_?NumericQ, _}], First]
```

which returns

> {{5, -1, -2, -3}, {g, e, a, c}}